# Get other applications icon uri?

Tags: android, icons, android-appwidget

I have an Android appwidget which shows icons of other applications on it.

I get the other applications icons with appInfo.loadIcon and then I set it to the widgets with setImageViewBitmap.

The problem is that if I have too many icons on the widget, I get "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" error. I understand that it's from a size limit and the solution it to use the image uri instead of the bitmap itself.

Is there an accessible URI to other applications' icons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]`, where `[res type]` in your case would be `drawable`. The package and name would have to come from the `ResolveInfo` or wherever you are getting your data.

Answer (score 15):

In case you don't know the resource name, you can also access resources by their id:

```
android.resource://[package]/[res_id]
```

The resource id of the app icon is available in the `ApplicationInfo` of the app:

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
if(appInfo.icon != 0) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + appInfo.icon);
}
```

Comment: For anyone coming to this answer post "Adaptive Icons" were introduced, this no longer seems to work for the Adaptive Icons

Answer (score 8):

While [@CommonWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121959/383793) is good in many cases, I find that this is often easier:
`android.resource://[package]/[res id]` - especially when you want a reference to for instance the launcher icon of some other app.