# Get other applications icon using uri

Tags: android, icons, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget and I want to show other installed applications' launcher icon on it. I am able to get the icons using either of the following two codes

```
pkgInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
```

OR

```
context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pkgInfo.packageName);
```

where `pkgInfo` is the instance of [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)

Everything works fine except for a couple of apps, which do not show their icons and there is no error printed in the logs. According to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121959/829617) we can also use URIs to get the drawables.

My question is if `android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]` is the URI then how to get the `[res name]`? And how to get the drawable of OTHER application icons from this URI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was while converting `Drawable` to `Bitmap`. The conversion was required as `RemoteViews` do not have a method `setImageDrawable` that can be used with an `ImageView`. Making the below change fixed the problem.

**Before**

`Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();`

**After**

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't know the resource name, you can also access resources by their id:

```
android.resource://[package]/[res_id]
```

The resource id of the app icon is available in the `ApplicationInfo` of the app:

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
if(appInfo.icon != 0) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + appInfo.icon);
}
```