# Android: Loading app icon uri of some apps are invalid and wont load

Tags: android, android-glide, android-package-managers, appicon

I have a RecyclerView that fetchs the user's installed app which include it's icon. I wanna load the app's drawable icon to an ImageView via its URI. Loading the drawable directly using `setImageDrawable()`  causes hiccups to the UI thread. Lazy loading it using an Image Loader like `Glide` was my choice of solution for such problem.

Solution tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21993055/13196984
I used that answer but it doesn't load all the icons. Here's my code snippet and a snapshot from my phone.

Code:

How I get the Apps info

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        ArrayList<InstalledApp> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
            if (pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName) != null) {
                String appName = String.valueOf(app.loadLabel(pm));
                int icon = app.icon;
                String packageName = app.packageName;
                installedApps.add(new InstalledApp(appName, icon, packageName));

            }

        }
```

`InstalledApp` is my created custom Object but I'll still include it.

```
    public InstalledApp(String appName, int appIcon,String packageName) {
        this.appName = appName;
        this.appIcon = appIcon;
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public int getAppIcon() {
        return appIcon;
    }

    public void setAppIcon(int appIcon) {
        this.appIcon = appIcon;
    }

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }

    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }
}
```

Here's how I load the image from the `InstalledApp` Object

```
 if(app.getAppIcon() != 0) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + app.getPackageName() + "/" + app.getAppIcon());
            Glide.with(activity).load(uri).into(holder.appIconIV);
        }
```

[Screenhot of the RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/564rt.png)

Hope you can help me. :)